# SharePoint 2013 custom 401 page layout - access denied

Tags: access-denied

In SharePoint 2010 I used `Set-SPCustomLayoutsPage -Identity AccessDenied (...)` for adding my custom Access Denied page. When I do this in SharePoint 2013 it does not take effect. If I run Get-SPCustomLayoutsPage the field has been updated, but it still redirects to the standard 401 page.

Seems like others are experiencing the same. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949794/sharepoint-2013-custom-pages

Has anyone been able to set custom pages?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you do an IIS reset after the command to force the IIS and Sharepoint to pick up your changes

**EDIT after update:**

Also the [Technet example for 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607768.aspx) looks like this

```
Set-SPCustomLayoutsPage –Identity "_layouts/accessdenied.aspx" –RelativePath 
"/_layouts/custompages/myaccessdenied.aspx" –WebApplication "http://server_name/mywebapp"
```

So, the Identity should now be the path to the standard access denied page and not just the name of the page.

**EDIT again:**

Seems the Technet article is incorrect since it do mention using the page names in all other documentation except in the example..

Comment: Thanks. I did try iisreset, but it still doesn't work...

Comment: OK, can you type out the full command you are calling?

Comment: The full command is `Set-SPCustomLayoutsPage -Identity AccessDenied -RelativePath "/_layouts/15/MyCustomAccessDenied.aspx" -WebApplication "htp://sp/"` WHen I run the command `Get-SPCustomLayoutsPage` I see that it updates the value correctly.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, but it gives en exception. I think the example is wrong because -Identity is mapped to an enumerator.

The Error I get is this: Cannot bind parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert value "_layouts/accessdenied.aspx" to type "Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication+SPCustomPage". Error: "Unable to match the identifier name _layouts/accessdenied.aspx to a valid enumerator name.  Specify one of the following enumerator names and try again: None, AccessDenied, Confirmation, Error, Login, RequestAccess, Signout, WebDeleted"

Comment: Yeah. the Technet is messing things up, as usual!

Comment: I posted feedback on technet about the code example.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official note about this, but it seems like this is a known issue. Expected to be fixed with CU in Feb, 2014.

Until then you are up with the following:

- Create a Http handler to handle all these
- Manually update error pages in _layouts (not recommended)